# how do recursive parameters work?

Tags: java

```
public static int exponent(int baseNum, int exp) { 
     if (exp == 0) return 1; 
     else return baseNum * exponent(baseNum, --exp); 
}
```

I don't understand how the two parameters work in this recursive method. Is baseNum value transfered to exponent multiplied by baseNum then returned? Then the second parameter (exp) does the same until it reaches the base case?
If you could help me visualize or break down how this works that would be great! Thank you.

Comment: There are no recursive parameters. There are only methods that are called recursively. Each method invocation is called with new arguments (values) that are bound to new parameters. On a piece of paper, walk through the *values* supplied to each recursive call and reason about the logic given those.

Comment: If you step through the code in your debugger you will see how the stack works and what the values are at each level/call.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example call to this recursive method using 2 and 4 for the arguments~(:

- exponent(2, 4)

  - => 2 * exponent(2, 3)

    - => 2 * exponent(2, 2)

      - => 2 * exponent(2, 1)

        - => 2 * exponent(2, 0) <- exp == 0, returns 1 so no more recursive calls

so working back up the chain:

- 2 * (1) => 2
- 2 * (2) => 4
- 2 * (4) => 8
- 2 * (8) => 16

A problem with this particular method is that if you were to pass in a negative value for exp on first call, you would get infinite recursion. Better to check (exp <= 0) instead

Comment: as long as you don't implement `exponent(2, -1)` to return 1, because that's just wrong! but yeah, watch out with your edge cases, make sure they are always reached!

Answer (score 1):

Recursive method `exponent()` calls itself if second argument `exp` is not 0, and uses returned result in further calculation. By each call, `exp` is decreased by 1, so finally (if initially > 0) it meets terminal condition.

A simple sequence diagram to illustrate:

```
exponent(2, 3)
     | ----------> exponent(2, 2)
     |                  | ----------> exponent(2, 1)
     |                  |                  | ----------> exponent(2, 0)
     |                  |                  | <---------- returns 1  // terminal condition
     |                  | <---------- returns 2 * 1 = 2
     | <---------- returns 2 * 2 = 4
returns 2 * 4 = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the method the first time, say exponent(10,5) this means the recursive method gets called 5 times.

Each time exp is reduced by 1 right before calling the recursive method. The parameters are passed into the method. They are local variables, so they only exist inside the method.

exponent(10,5)
will call

`else return 10 * exponent(10,4)`

then

`else return 10 * exponent(10,3)`

then

`else return 10 * exponent(10,2)`

… etc

until exp ==0.

Answer (score 0):

`exponent()` is a method for calculating a number (`baseNum`) to the power of another number (`exp`) by simply multiplying the number with itself `exp` number of times.

If the exponent is `0`, then it will return `1` since every integer to the power of 0 equals 1 (with the exception of 0 itself, which is not covered for some reason).

Let us say that we want to calculate `2^3`. We will call the method by writing `exponent(2,3)`. What happens is the following:

- `return 2*exponent(2,2);`

Since `exponent(2,2)`is the same thing as `return 2*exponent(2,1);`, we can instead write it as the following:

- `return 2*2*exponent(2,1);`

`exponent(2,1)` is the same thing as `2*exponent(2,0)` which is `2*1` (when `exp` is `0`, we return `1`). So we can instead write this as `return 2*2*2*1`;

So we wanted to calculate `2^3` and the method called itself three times and multiplied `2` with itself every time and finally returned the answer of `2*2*2*1`.

Do not forget that `0^0` is *not* `1`. If you call `exponent(0,0)` you will get `1` which is wrong.